# Define array in env file for snapshot

Tags: fastlane

In my projet I have several targets to build several variants of my app. In order to handle this with snapshot, I use environnements as described here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/docs/Advanced.md#environment-variables

It works fine for defining my scheme but I do not manage to use it for languages.

.env.first_environment

```
SCHEME = MyScheme

LANGUAGES = en-GB,es-ES
```

Snapfile

```
languages([
    ENV['LANGUAGES']
])

# The name of the scheme which contains the UI Tests
scheme ENV['SCHEME']
```

If I have only one language it works, but as soon as there is a comma in the env variable, I have some problems. When I launch fastlane I have:

```
+----------------------------+------------------------------+
|                Summary for snapshot 1.2.2                 |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+
| workspace                  | ./my_app.xcworkspace         |
| devices                    | ["iPhone 4s"]                |
| languages                  | ["en-GB,es-ES"]              |
| output_directory           | ./fastlane/Snapshots/MyScheme|
| ios_version                | 9.1                          |
| stop_after_first_error     | false                        |
| skip_open_summary          | false                        |
| clear_previous_screenshots | false                        |
| buildlog_path              | ~/Library/Logs/snapshot      |
| clean                      | false                        |
| scheme                     | My-Scheme                    |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+
```

For the language option I have `"en-GB,es-ES"` instead of `"en-GB","es-ES"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from @AliSoftware:

In env file

```
...
LANGUAGES = "en-GB,es-ES"
...
```

In Snapfile

```
...
languages(
    ENV['LANGUAGES'].split(",")
)
...
```

Thanks.